# How to upsert correctly using ReactiveMongo

Tags: mongodb, scala, reactivemongo

Assume I have this entry in the collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c56160e4b6929067972b4c8"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

The code I have implemented to do the upsert is as follows:

```
  def insert(item: Item): Future[Option[Item]] = {
    val selector = BSONDocument("name" -> item.name, "attributes" -> BSONDocument("$elemMatch" -> Json.toJson(item.attributes.head)))

    val updateModifier = BSONDocument(
      f"$$push" -> BSONDocument("attributes" -> Json.toJson(item.attributes.head)))

    itemsCollection.flatMap(
      _.findAndUpdate(selector, updateModifier, upsert = true)
        .map(_.result[Item])
    )
  }
```

However, when executing this code, the collection is updated as follows:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5c56160e4b6929067972b4c8"),
    "name" : "car",
    "attributes" : [
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        },
        {
            "color" : "blue",
            "qty" : 10
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that a duplicate entry is added. That should not happen according to the upsert logic.

How can I prevent the duplicate entry from getting inserted? What is wrong with the code?

Comment: First try it in mongoshell

Comment: After consulting with people on the MongoDB channel, apparently this is NOT a trivial thing to do i.e. upsert on an embedded document. Mongo is an insanely difficult tool to work with when the document has even a sniff of complexity. Flat documents are fine. The resultant queries are simple. But as soon as the data structure becomes complex then the queries become very difficult to write.